# Each vehicle has a number plate: 0001-9999, what is the chance that 2 random cars will have identical digit in their plate?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

What is the chance that there won't be a identical digit in two random plates if there are totally $9999$ plates for which number sequence varies from $0001 - 9999.$ So, the chance that two random plates will have 0 in them  is $(10^4-9^4)^2= 11826721 $ The same goes with other numbers 1-9. Should I simply multiply $(10^4-9^4) \cdot 10$?

Comment: Can we assume random numbers from $1$ to $9999$ ? In this case, we have $9999$ possibilities.

Comment: "The number of unique plates is $10\times 10\times 10\times 9$"?  Why times nine at the end?  There are $9999$ numbers between $0001$ and $9999$.  Lets count them... the first number is $0001$.  The second number is $0002$ and so on until you reach the ninethousandninehundredninety eigth number as being $9998$, etc...

Comment: Do you require that the identical digit be at the same place in the plate? Do, for instance, 1234 and 4321 contain identical digits as per your conditions?

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, now it sounds reasonable, but I chose 9, because there is 9 options to choose from 1 to 9.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri No, it doesn't have to be at the same place.

Comment: "but I chose 9 because there is 9 options to choose from 1 to 9"  What does that have to do with anything?  They didn't say that each vehicle has a number plate whose first digit is a number from 0 to 9, second digit is a number from 0 to 9, third digit is a number from 0 to 9 and fourth digit is a number from 1 to 9... No restriction was put on the fourth digit like that and zero is an allowable fourth digit except in the special case of the first three digits all also being zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, I really thought that there is a implied restriction and that the last digit can't be $0$. But do you know how to solve it, is my result at all reasonable?

Comment: Use conditional probabilities: given the first plate has $x$ unique digits, what is the probability that the second plate has at least one number in common? Calculate this for $x$ in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and add the results.

Comment: Don't forget to multiply each by the probability that the first plate has $x$ unique digits before summing

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach in my opinion is to first make the simplification that we allow the license plate to be $0000$ as well., making it a clean $10^4$ possibilities where we don't need to give zero any special treatment until the very end where we subtract this away as having been a possibility.

We continue counting the number of ways of having two plates sharing at least one similar digit between them with inclusion-exclusion based on the events "Both plates have at least one zero", "Both plates have at least one 1", "Both plates have at least one 2", etc...

The number of plates containing at least one zero is equal to the number of plates minus the number of plates which contain no zeroes and would be $10^4-9^4$.  The number of ways that *both* plates have at least one zero would then be $(10^4-9^4)^2$

The number of plates containing at least one zero and at least one $1$ can be counted again by breaking down with inclusion exclusion as the number of plates minus those plates which are missing at least one of 0 or 1 and would be $10^4-9^4-9^4+8^4$ making the number of ways that both plates simultaneously contain at least one $0$ and at least one $1$ as being $(10^4-9^4-9^4+8^4)^2$

Continue in this fashion and correctly apply inclusion-exclusion across all of these events to get the count.  Then, remove from your count the possibilities where either user had the "bad" license plate of $0000$ and the other had a $0$.

Finally, divide by the total number of possible pairs of license plates to get the probability.

Comment: I don't think I understand your reasoning, because you are calculating pairs with at least one zero and at least one 1, but the question is, how many plates are there with no identical digit in them. I think $9^4-8^4$ would mean, how many plates are there with both zero and 1 in them, but I only need to calculate how many plates are there that don't have identical digit in them, not whole number.

Comment: @user it has been quite a while since I last looked at this problem... I don't really remember it.  Looking at it again, my interpretation was that "2 cars do have an identical digit in their plates" would include such situations as (1234,1567) since both cars have a $1$ in their plate in the first position, (1234,5671) since both cars have a $1$ in their plate even though it isn't in the same position, (1234,4321) because both cars have a 1 in their plate among others, (1111,2221) because both cars have a 1 in their plate, etc... that is if the set of digits used for the first...

Comment: ... has some overlap with the set of digits used by the second.  Now, admittedly I did not finish the total calculations, because it is tedious to do so and that is work that *you* should be putting in, not me.  I did however explain the set up and how to begin and continue.  Yes, I had specifically talked about sharing a $0$ or sharing a $1$... and the same logic works for sharing a $5$ or sharing a $6$ or any other combination of digits.  As I suggested, you should continue by applying the same logic to *any* collection of digits which could be shared of any quantity...

Comment: ... and having done so will let you arrive at a final answer.